# Why is reject and throw handled differently from async functions in Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm given an array of promises that I'm passing to `Promise.all`, but I was getting `Uncaught (in promise) Error` and I couldn't understand why. Trying to reproduce the error I've come to the following minimal example.

```
Promise
  .all([
    new Promise(async () => {
      throw new Error('thrown');
    }),
  ])
  .then(results => {
    console.log('results', results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  })
```

Running that you will see an "Uncaught" message in your console.

The example is fixable by removing the `async` keyword. But, assuming I'm given the promises from a library I don't have control over, how do I make this work?

Another way to "fix" it is by rewriting it like this

```
Promise
  .all([
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      reject(new Error('rejected'));
    }),
  ])
  .then(results => {
    console.log('results', results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  })
```

Why does this work differently from the `throw` version? I thought the throw would be handled as a rejection.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @CertainPerformance's answer below, my example can be simplified even further, like this

```
Promise
  .all([
    new Promise(async () => {
      throw new Error('thrown');
    }),
  ])
  .then(() => console.log('resolve'))
  .catch(() => console.log('reject'));
```

And then getting rid of `Promise.all` altogether like so

```
new Promise(async () => {
  throw new Error('thrown');
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

And since `async` is pretty much only syntactic sugar around promises, the above can be rewritten like this, and still show the same behavior

```js
new Promise(() => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    throw new Error('thrown')
  });
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

`throw` inside a promise rejects that promise, so the above can be rewritten like this

```js
new Promise(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('instead of throw')
  });
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

And all that does, is immediately rejects the promise, and we have an easier way to do that:

```js
new Promise(() => {
  return new Promise.reject('instead of throw');
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

And with that I think I fully understand why things are working the way they do.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a longer example that more realistically mimics my actual code

```js
function textPromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('data from fetch');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function fetch(ok) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    ok,
    text: textPromise(),
  });
}

async function handleResponse(response) {
  const data = response.text;
  
  if (!response.ok) {
    const resolvedData = await data;
    throw new Error(resolvedData);
  }
  
  return data;
}

function post(ok) {
  const promise = fetch(ok)
    .then(response => handleResponse(response));

  return promise;
}

const validatorPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  post(false).then(response => {
    if (response === 'data from fetch') {
      resolve('validated OK');
    } else {
      resolve('validated NOK');
    }
  });
});

Promise
  .all([validatorPromise])
  .then(text => console.log('text', text))
  .catch(() => console.log('reject'));
```

That example can most certainly be simplified, and I will try to do that. But it shows the same problem I tried to show in my original example.

The only code I have control over for now is the last `Promise.all` stuff. I'm given an array of "validator promises", and I need to handle when something in there throws an error

**EDIT 3:**

And here's a simplified version of the example above, but that still retains the async function

```js
async function handleResponse(response) {
  throw new Error('resolvedData');
}

function post() {
  return Promise.resolve('').then(handleResponse);
}

const validatorPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  post().then(() => resolve('validated OK'));
});

validatorPromise
  .then(text => console.log('text', text))
  .catch(() => console.log('reject'));
```

(The async function will be wrapped in a promise by the JS interpreter, so essentially we will still get `new Promise(async ...`, but it's not as obvious here)

Comment: you would never make the promise constructor `async` - doing so implies you'll need to use `await` (which you don't) - and using await implies there's a promise being awaited ... so, no need for the promise constructor in the first place - perhaps you could show the *actual* code you are having an issue with ... chances are you don't even need a Promise constructor

Comment: @slebetman It's also interpreted as a rejection in the Promise constructor, if the Promise constructor callback fails to finish. (but an async function which throws will return a rejected Promise, rather than failing entirely)

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right, the promise constructor isn't async. But to create a minimal example, that's what I did. I'll try to add an example that's closer to actual code.

Comment: your original minimal example made no sense, since you were using async promise constructor

Comment: I think you should accept @CertainPerformance answer and start a new question. To many edits and distructions. Your code had an error, it was pointed out. And it is totally unclear what your goals are from now on. And if you say that you don't have any control over any code accept for Promise.all, then - no luck for you. handleResponse() is async and should be waited on or have a then().catch() chain on it. But it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a function to `new Promise`, that function is called immediately with `resolve` and `reject` parameters. If the function *throws synchronously* (that is, the function throws before synchronously completing), the Promise will reject, without requiring the `resolve` or `reject` parameters (if used) to be called.

When the async function is invoked, it will return a rejected Promise, but it'll *still return something*. In contrast, a synchronous function which throws an error will not return at all; execution stops, and the `Promise.all` knows that since execution stopped during execution that it should look for a `.catch` handler and invoke it.

When neither `resolve` nor `reject` parameters are called, *and* the function doesn't appear to the `Promise.all` to throw synchronously (in this case, the async function returns a Promise, rather than failing entirely), the Promise will remain unresolved forever. That's what's happening in your first snippet, so neither the `.then` nor the `.catch` chained off the `Promise.all` run.

The same behavior is exhibited with a plain Promise, without the `Promise.all`:

```js
// Will remain unresolved forever, because the constructor callback successfully completes
// (and returns a rejected Promise, which goes unused)
new Promise(async () => {
  throw new Error('thrown');
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

```js
// Will throw synchronously, and therefore reject:
new Promise(() => {
  throw new Error('thrown');
})
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('rejected'));
```

The reasonable thing to do is: invoke the Promise constructor with logical paths that always eventually lead to either its `resolve` or `reject` parameter being called. (Or you can throw an error, if the Promise constructor callback isn't `async`)

---

Given the new code, which can be reduced to:

```js
const post = ok => ok ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();

const validatorPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  post(false).then(response => {
    if (response === 'data from fetch') {
      resolve('validated OK');
    } else {
      resolve('validated NOK');
    }
  });
});

Promise
  .all([validatorPromise])
  .then(text => console.log('text', text))
  .catch(() => console.log('reject'));
```

The `validatorPromise` function is broken. It does not catch errors from `post` - it only works if `post` does not reject. If you can't change `validatorPromise` (nor anything it depends on), the library you're using can be considered to be broken, because it does not handle errors. Post an issue on its github, or fork the library and fix it yourself.